# Table modal won't read any other rows reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, asp.net

I have a problem it only reads the first row item, I don't know why it does that. How can I use foreach loop for this, or any kind of code so it will work,  because it doesn't read any other row besides the first one? I'm so confused because I haven't done reactjs before.

PS: the data came from an API from asp.net:

[image: you can check the image here]

```
renderItem(d, i) {
    debugger

    return <tr key={i} >
  <td> {d.Employee_ID} </td>
        <td>{d.Employee_Name}</td>
        <td>{d.Address}</td> 
        <td><center>
  <button className ="btn btn-info" onClick={() => this.props.onClick(i) }   data-toggle="modal" data-target="#UpdateEmployee">Edit</button></center></td>
  <td><center><button className ="btn btn-danger">Delete</button></center></td>

<div className="modal fade" id="UpdateEmployee" role="dialog">
         <div className="modal-dialog">
           <div className="modal-content">
              <div className="modal-header">
                 <button type="button" className="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                <h4 className="modal-title">Update Employee</h4>
              </div>
          <div className="container">
            <div className="modal-body">
                <table> 
                <tbody>
                <tr>
                <td>Name</td>
                <td> <input type="text"value={d.Employee_Name} /> </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                <td>Address</td>
                <td><input type="text" value={d.Address} />  </td>
                </tr>
                </tbody>
                </table>
            </div>
            </div>
            <div className="modal-footer">
              <botton className="btn btn-info"> Update Employee</botton>
              <button type="button" className="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
 </tr>
}
```

Comment: Patricia you are only passing one row d to the render method in order to use loop kind of functionality called map in react, you have to pass in the whole array right and then you can call arrayName.map() and then the tr tag will come.

Comment: ohh but im confuse how can i use the map ... im sorry im just new to this @zenwraight

Comment: Ohk can you paste whole code how is the value d coming, I want to know that... because my assumption is d should be an element of the array

Comment: {jsonReturnedValue.map((d,i) => this.renderItem(d,i))} @zenwraight I dont know how to paste the whole code in the comment but thats how i call it on the table

Comment: aah so you are already iterating over the array jsonReturnedValue but when you click on the edit button, you are saying the modal doesn't pop up for all the rows right ? it is only popping up for first row right  ?

Comment: @zenwraight so close.. it pop up for all rows how ever the input only reads the first row only when i click the other rows it output the same data on first row :/ >.< im such a noob sorry

Comment: Can you check the value of i,  my guess is that the value of i is staying constant that's why i gets set for the first row as i=0 and for the rest rows also it's i=0 and that's why edit action on any modal is calling the first row

Comment: @zenwraight sooo should i use function for loop? the only place i call the i is renderItem(d, i) {
    debugger

    return <tr key={i} > ... im not sure im getting you.. how can i insert a loop.. ive worked on php before i use foreach here but i dont know how ill work in react i dont know the terms.. im just so lost right now been working on this since yesterday my brain is messed up ..

Comment: Don't worry Patricia we will get this working today only... before return just place console.log(i); and then run the app again and click on edit button for each row and check the console, and let me know what value they show, otherwise I have a more cleaner way to fix this ... :)

Comment: @zenwraight wait where? it shows errors o.o

Comment: So right click on your page and click on inspect, it will open a right side window, there select the console tab and you see anything that you print using console.log();

Comment: it doesn't output anything.... even in the console but when < i tried input type="text"value={i} the number is 0 @zenwraight

Comment: Ohk my assumption is that it's taking in same i value for all the rows as i = 0 ... do one thing change jsonReturnedValue.map((d,i) to -> jsonReturnedValue.map((d,2) and run the app and click on the edit button, I think this time it should show only row 2 values for all the edit clicks

Comment: @zenwraight uhmm but when i do that only the first row of the table shows... all the other rows are gone.. hmm i will paste the whole code below this conversation..

Comment: I added some code, may be something like this should work so on clicking edit, I am calling a separate function and passing d to it and that function basically returns a modal.. I hope it works...can't really test it

Answer (score 0):

```
import React from 'react';
import 'whatwg-fetch';

export default class employee extends React.Component {

    constructor() {
        super();
          this.state = { jsonReturnedValue: [] }

        }

    renderItem(d, i) {
        debugger

        return <tr key={i} >

      <td> {d.Employee_ID} </td>
            <td>{d.Employee_Name}</td>
            <td>{d.Address }</td> 
            <td><center><button className ="btn btn-info" onClick={() => this.props.onClick(i) }   data-toggle="modal" data-target="#UpdateEmployee">Edit</button></center></td>
      <td><center><button className ="btn btn-danger">Delete</button></center></td>

    <div className="modal fade" id="UpdateEmployee" role="dialog">
             <div className="modal-dialog">
               <div className="modal-content">
                  <div className="modal-header">
                     <button type="button" className="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                    <h4 className="modal-title">Update Employee</h4>
                  </div>
              <div className="container">
                <div className="modal-body">
                    <table> 
                    <tbody>
                    <tr>
                    <td>Name</td>
                    <td> <input type="text"value={d.Employee_Name} /> </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                    <td>Address</td>
                    <td><input type="text" value={d.Address} />  </td>
                    </tr>
                    </tbody>
                    </table>
                </div>
                </div>
                <div className="modal-footer">
                  <botton className="btn btn-info"> Update Employee</botton>
                  <button type="button" className="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
     </tr>
    }

    componentDidMount() {
      fetch('http://localhost:5118/api/employeedetails/getemployeedetails')
      .then((response) => {
        return response.json()})
      .then((json) => {
        this.setState({jsonReturnedValue : json});
      });
  }

    render() {


      let {jsonReturnedValue} = this.state;
        return(

            <div>
        <div className="container">
            <h1> Listof Employees </h1>
          <button className ='btn btn-warning right ' data-toggle="modal" data-target="#AddEmployee"> Add an Employee</button>
            <table className= "table table-bordered">

                <tbody>
                 <tr>
                      <th>ID</th>
                      <th>Name</th>
                      <th>Address</th>
                      <th>Update</th>
                      <th>Delete</th>
                 </tr>
                    {jsonReturnedValue.map((d,i) => this.renderItem(d,i))}
                </tbody>
            </table>
          </div>
        {/*Adding*/}
          <div className="modal fade" id="AddEmployee" role="dialog">
             <div className="modal-dialog">
               <div className="modal-content">
                  <div className="modal-header">
                    <button type="button" className="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                    <h4 className="modal-title">Add New Employee</h4>
                  </div>
              <div className="container">
                <div className="modal-body">
                    <table> 
                    <tbody>
                    <tr>
                    <td>Name</td>
                    <td>
                    <input type="text"
                           name={this.props.Employee_Name}
                           className="EmployeeDetails"
                           value={this.props.value}
                           onChange={this.props.handleChange}/> 
                    </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                    <td>Address</td>
                    <td>
                     <input type="text"
                           name={this.props.address}
                           className="EmployeeDetails"
                           value={this.props.value}
                           onChange={this.props.handleChange}/> 
                    </td>


                    </tr>
                    </tbody>
                    </table>

                </div>
                </div>
                <div className="modal-footer">
                  <botton className="btn btn-info" onClick = {this.save}> Add Employee</botton>
                  <button type="button" className="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
    </div>
        );
    }
}`
```

Answer (score 0):

I think something like this should work

```
import React from 'react';
import 'whatwg-fetch';

export default class employee extends React.Component {

let index = -1;
constructor() {
    super();
      this.state = { jsonReturnedValue: [] ,
      name: '',
      address: ''
      }

    }

renderItem(d, i) {
    debugger
    index++;
    let name = d.Employee_Name;
    let address = d.Address;
    return <tr key={i} >

  <td> {d.Employee_ID} </td>
        <td>{d.Employee_Name}</td>
        <td>{d.Address }</td> 
        <td><center><button className ="btn btn-info" onClick={() => this.props.onClick(i) }   data-toggle="modal" data-target="#UpdateEmployee">Edit</button></center></td>
  <td><center><button className ="btn btn-danger">Delete</button></center></td>

<div className="modal fade" id="UpdateEmployee" role="dialog">
         <div className="modal-dialog">
           <div className="modal-content">
              <div className="modal-header">
                 <button type="button" className="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                <h4 className="modal-title">Update Employee</h4>
              </div>
          <div className="container">
            <div className="modal-body">
                <table> 
                <tbody>
                <tr>
                <td>Name</td>
                <td> <input type="text"value={this.state.jsonReturnedValue[index].Employee_Name} /> </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                <td>Address</td>
                <td><input type="text" value={this.state.jsonReturnedValue[index].Address} />  </td>
                </tr>
                </tbody>
                </table>
            </div>
            </div>
            <div className="modal-footer">
              <botton className="btn btn-info"> Update Employee</botton>
              <button type="button" className="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
 </tr>
}

componentDidMount() {
  fetch('http://localhost:5118/api/employeedetails/getemployeedetails')
  .then((response) => {
    return response.json()})
  .then((json) => {
    this.setState({jsonReturnedValue : json});
  });
}

render() {


  let {jsonReturnedValue} = this.state;
    return(

        <div>
    <div className="container">
        <h1> Listof Employees </h1>
      <button className ='btn btn-warning right ' data-toggle="modal" data-target="#AddEmployee"> Add an Employee</button>
        <table className= "table table-bordered">

            <tbody>
             <tr>
                  <th>ID</th>
                  <th>Name</th>
                  <th>Address</th>
                  <th>Update</th>
                  <th>Delete</th>
             </tr>
                {jsonReturnedValue.map((d,i) => this.renderItem(d,i))}
            </tbody>
        </table>
      </div>
    {/*Adding*/}
      <div className="modal fade" id="AddEmployee" role="dialog">
         <div className="modal-dialog">
           <div className="modal-content">
              <div className="modal-header">
                <button type="button" className="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                <h4 className="modal-title">Add New Employee</h4>
              </div>
          <div className="container">
            <div className="modal-body">
                <table> 
                <tbody>
                <tr>
                <td>Name</td>
                <td>
                <input type="text"
                       name={this.props.Employee_Name}
                       className="EmployeeDetails"
                       value={this.props.value}
                       onChange={this.props.handleChange}/> 
                </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                <td>Address</td>
                <td>
                 <input type="text"
                       name={this.props.address}
                       className="EmployeeDetails"
                       value={this.props.value}
                       onChange={this.props.handleChange}/> 
                </td>


                </tr>
                </tbody>
                </table>

            </div>
            </div>
            <div className="modal-footer">
              <botton className="btn btn-info" onClick = {this.save}> Add Employee</botton>
              <button type="button" className="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
</div>
    );
}
}
```

Comment: it says Unexpected token (12:12) on createModal = (d) => { im not sure whay im doing wrong :'(

Comment: may be the way I was defining the method was wrong..check now... I am also kind of not a pro with react but I have done this kind of stuffs with modals...

Comment: i tried rearranging the lines etc.. but it wont call the modal anymore ..

Comment: i dont know what happened it only shows the address but not the name and yet it only calls the first row again :(

Comment: am i dont know whats happening i have like 989 errors saying bundle.js:1002 Warning: setState(...): Cannot update during an existing state transition (such as within `render` or another component's constructor). Render methods should be a pure function of props and state; constructor side-effects are an anti-pattern, but can be moved to `componentWillMount`.

Comment: Ohk I was taking d.Employee_name instead of d.Employee_name

Comment: ya can remove my approach it's not doing the work, I thought it would be a hacky way....hmm...

Comment: Give it a last try Patricia ...then I will try again tmw, I have updated my answer...

Comment: it is not calling the 1st row anymore its calling the 9th row 0,0 whoa im not sure whats happening anymore im so lost

Comment: aah that's because 9th row is the last entry and because the name and employee values are getting set during initial run... hmm

Comment: See my answer now, you must be getting hang of it what's happening now...

Comment: ive changed it by the code you gave me still it work that way (only calls first row) im so lost i don't know whats happening anymore.. thank you so much for the help im sorry i dont know whats happening haha

Comment: oh wait... did you just posted it? ill try it wait

Comment: interesting ... ohk Patricia, I will try again tmw with other solutions but if you solve it make a comment here and update the code, so I will upvote your working answer :) gn

Comment: thank you so much for wasting time on my code hahaha gn ill try my best i still have the whole day to work on it.. but my brain hurts lol hahaha thanks again, really for real this time thanks

Comment: Updated one last time for today before turning my laptop off

Comment: I know the feeling, I was also scratching my head on react like this 2 weeks ago ... you will get the hang of it eventually

Comment: @zenwaright hey wait ill check on it i just ate lunch

Comment: apparently the let index part has an error i place it under the rendernewitem however nothing really changed.. same problem idky

Comment: however it work whenever i change the index number i need to put some forloop dunno how

Comment: ya so this is what I was trying to say for the start like the index i is getting stick at i=0 only that's why you are only seeing the row 1  values, if your i gets increment with respesct to your looping then you would be able to see the correct info for all the modals